# How can I display the loading indicator until ajax is completed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I want to display a loading spinner until my **messages** finished loading.

I implemented my spinner in my `Message.vue`:

```js
import backend from '...'

export default {
  mounted: function() {
    this.loadMessages();
  },
  methods: {
    loadMessages() {
      var self = this;
      backend.getMessages().then(function(resp) {
        self.previousDate = null;
        self.messages = resp.data;
        self.openLoader();
      });
    },
    openLoader() {
      let loader = this.$loading.show({
        loader: 'spinner',
        color: '#e32339',
        canCancel: true,
        container: this.$refs.loadingContainer
      });

      setTimeout(() => {
        loader.hide()
      }, 2500)
    },
  }
}
```

My spinner is displayed over the container for 2500 milliseconds, but I'm just simulating it without knowing when the AJAX request has finished. I quite don´t understand how to display the spinner til the AJAX request is completed. Right now it just displays it for 2500 milliseconds.

My `backend.getMessages()` method looks like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const host = /* process... */

export default {
  getMessages: function (peer) {
    return axios.get(`${host}/api/messages`, {
      params: {
        me:      localStorage.getItem("user_id"),
        device:  localStorage.getItem("device_id"),
        peer: peer
      }
    }) 
  },
  //...
}
```

Comment: `self = this`? This is not python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loader should be shown *before* the start of your request. Note that [`axios.get()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) returns a `Promise` that resolves when the request is complete, so you could use [`Promise.prototype.finally`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) off of that `Promise` to hide the loader:

```js
mounted() {
  // show loader while fetching messages...
  const loader = this.$loading.show()

  backend.getMessages()
    .then(resp => /*...*/)
    .finally(() => loader.hide())
}
```

Here's another way to write it with [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
async mounted() {
  // show loader while fetching messages...
  const loader = this.$loading.show()

  try {
    const resp = await backend.getMessages()
    /*...*/

  } finally {
     loader.hide()
  }
}
```

Comment: Is .finally not part of try catch and will be executed regardless if an exception is handled?
right now my loader does not hide

Comment: Yes, `.finally` always runs after the `Promise` settles. What code have you tried? Can you link to a reproduction in Codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a `var loading` in your data.
- Display `<div v-if="loading">Spinner here</div>`
- Then

```js
getMessages: function (peer) {
    this.loading = true; // AJAX request is loading
    return axios.get(`${host}/api/messages`, {
      params: {
        me:      localStorage.getItem("user_id"),
        device:  localStorage.getItem("device_id"),
        peer: peer
      }
    })
  },


loadMessages() {
      var self = this;
      backend.getMessages().then(function(resp) {
        self.previousDate = null;
        self.messages = resp.data;
        self.openLoader();
        self.loading = false // spinner disappear
      });
    },
```

Comment: this should be self, i.e. self.loading = true;

Comment: getMessages() is in my backend file. I thought that such things doesn´t belong in the backend file. And also the backend file doesn´t know that loading exists or not?

Comment: yes, backend file doesn't know about frontend variables/elements unless you pass explicitly